# Command lnd not found even after installing lnd

Tags: bash, git

I tried installing lnd using the commands shown in the [installation guide](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md).
I used these commands:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd
cd lnd
make install
```

but when I try running the lnd command, I get this:

```bsh
Command 'lnd' not found
```

How can I solve this issue?
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

edit: I have go1.18.1 installed. I did execute the commands above, but nothing changed.
Here are the `$GOPATH` and `$PATH` variables:

```bsh
echo $GOPATH 
/usr/local/go
```

```bsh
echo $PATH
/home/ayoub/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ayoub/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Are the three commands shown in the question the only commands you executed from installation guide? There are instructions to install Go and set environment variables. Please show the output of `echo $GOPATH` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Please be more specific about how you followed the installation guide. Which section did you follow? [Building a development version from source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#building-a-development-version-from-source)? Did you install Go as written there or from the Ubuntu package repository? Did you set variable `GOPATH`? Did you run `make install` as `root`? Does a file `/usr/local/go/bin/lnd` exist? Show the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/go /usr/local/go/bin /usr/local/go/bin/lnd` and `echo $GOBIN`. Are you using a real Ubuntu system or maybe WSL?